# How to install Ubuntu LTS (Desktop) without unsupported components?

Tags: lts

Recently I realized that the 5 year support that comes with each LTS release is actually only limited to main and restricted components while universe and multiverse are community maintained which may or may not receive updates.

Is it possible to get Ubuntu LTS (Default Desktop - GNOME) installed without universe and multiverse enabled and also without any pakage from these branches? So that a user can be rest assured that their installation is 100% supported for 5 years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sure it is possible. All packages constituting the default Ubuntu desktop, including anything to run the Gnome Shell desktop, are all included in the Canonical "main" repository. That also includes default applications such as LibreOffice. This repository is maintained directly by Canonical for the life span of the edition.

Proceed with a default installation, but do not check the option to install multimedia support. Right after installation, disable the universe and multiverse repositories, which are enabled by default.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How shall I proceed to achieve that? Shall I use the mini.iso? Or install the Ubuntu LTS Server first and then proceed with the Desktop Environment installation? The Server install only includes the 'main' component.

Comment: I would not be surprised if a normal default Ubuntu desktop install only installed packages from Main, provided you uncheck Media codecs and proprietary drivers. It is then up to you to disable other repo's right after installation.

Comment: Does the default Desktop install only installs packages from 'main' component?

Comment: @Kratos already addressed in the second sentence of this answer. This answer is correct. To learn what goes into Main, Universe, and Multiverse pockets, see: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

Comment: Thank you so much. I was very much misinformed earlier. But now everything is clear.

Comment: @vanadium snapd comes installed out of the box. snapd as a package coming from the 'main' component will thus be supported for support period of an LTS release. But, what about the snap packages? The "Ubuntu Software" store also comes integrated with snap packages. Are they also supported for 5 years?

Comment: The snap packages are maintained by their individual maintainers, not by Canonical.

Comment: @vanadium Got it. Thanks again for the clarity.

Answer (score 3):

### Universe / Multiverse

- When installing, at the Updates and other software window, do not check **Install third-party software ...**
- Open **Software and Updates**
- Click **Ubuntu Software**
- Confirm that **Community-maintained ... (universe)** is not checked.
- Confirm that **Software restricted ... (multiverse)** is not checked.
- Close and reload.

Comment: Looks like I might be misinformed that the default Desktop installation also installs packages out of 'main' by default. I know there is an option to include drivers/codecs in the installer that installs them from restricted. Can you confirm this? That unless not installed explicitly. the installer only installs packages from the 'main' component.

Comment: I have always had to install Universe repository before installing items such as P7Zip, mkusb, etc from it.